# Implementing a reconnecting http client in twisted

Tags: couchdb, twisted

I am implementing a library module to serve as client for couchdb change notifications. I want to have the library in "continuous" mode, that is, the connection must remain open forever, or at least it must reconnect if the connection has been closed, so that couchdb has a channel to notify of any new changes happening in the database. I will then process those notifications to generate certain events (this is not yet implemented).

The approach that I have chosen is to use the ReconnectingClientFactory (which does automatic re-connection as per an elaborated algorithm) as basis for my Protocol Factory. Whenever the connection has been established, the buildProtocol method is called. In this method I create the protocol instance, and fire a callLater (immediately) to signal that the connection is ready. In the cdConnected function, I send the request and add a callback to process the received data (cbReceived).

The code does reconnection as expected, but I am having two different problems:

- the request is failing (no data is sent over the tcp connection), but I do not know why.
- an error is generated, even though the connection is closed cleanly.

Maybe somebody has an idea of what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

(edit: the "Connection was closed cleanly." error is being printed by myself, so it can be ignored)

Here is the code:

```
from   twisted.internet              import defer
from   twisted.internet.protocol     import ReconnectingClientFactory
from   twisted.web._newclient        import HTTP11ClientProtocol
from   twisted.web._newclient        import Request
from   twisted.web.client            import _parse

class MyReconnectingClientFactory(ReconnectingClientFactory):

    def __init__(self, reactor, cbConnected):
        self.reactor      = reactor
        self.cbConnected  = cbConnected

    def startedConnecting(self, connector):
        print 'Started to connect ...'

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        print 'Resetting reconnection delay'
        self.resetDelay()
        proto = HTTP11ClientProtocol()
        self.reactor.callLater(0, self.cbConnected, proto)
        return proto

    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        print 'Lost connection.  Reason:', reason
        ReconnectingClientFactory.clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason)

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        print 'Connection failed. Reason:', reason
        ReconnectingClientFactory.clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason)

def cbReceived(response):
    print response

def printError(failure):
    print "printError > %s" % (str(failure))

def cbConnected(proto):
    print "Sending request ..."
    req = Request(method, path, headers, bodyProducer)
    d = proto.request(req)
    d.addCallback(cbReceived).addErrback(printError)
    return d

from twisted.internet import reactor

uri='http://localhost:5984/cn/_changes?feed=continuous'
method='GET'
headers=None
bodyProducer=None

scheme, host, port, path = _parse(uri)
factory = MyReconnectingClientFactory(reactor, cbConnected)
reactor.connectTCP(host, port, factory)
reactor.run()
```

And here is the output:

```
Started to connect ...
Resetting reconnection delay
Sending request ...
printError > [Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): <class 'twisted.web._newclient.RequestGenerationFailed'>: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>>]
]
Lost connection.  Reason: [Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone'>: Connection was closed cleanly.
]
Started to connect ...
Resetting reconnection delay
Sending request ...
printError > [Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): <class 'twisted.web._newclient.RequestGenerationFailed'>: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>>]
]
Lost connection.  Reason: [Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone'>: Connection was closed cleanly.
]
```

Comment: `_newclient` is a private module in Twisted.  Be aware that if you import names from it, your code may break without warning in any new version of Twisted.  If you need functionality from this private module to be supported, please file a bug at http://twistedmatrix.com/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should take a look at the failures generated.  _newclient has a habit of throwing compound failures; these contain further failures.

I adapted your code a little:

```
def printError(failure):
print "printError > %r" % failure

from twisted.web import _newclient
if failure.check(_newclient.RequestGenerationFailed):
    print "printError: RequestGenerationFailed"
    for f in failure.value.reasons:
        print "printError > %r" % f
        print f.getTraceback()
```

You were doing a str() on failure and that's not a good way to get information about an exception.  Let repr take care of it, that's its job.

Using %r, I saw that it was actually giving me a RequestGenerationFailed.  That's a more interesting failure.  The failure value has reasons.

With my modification, the script gave this:

```
Started to connect ...
Resetting reconnection delay
Sending request ...
printError > <twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.web._newclient.RequestGenerationFailed'>>
printError: RequestGenerationFailed
printError > <twisted.python.failure.Failure <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1174, in mainLoop
    self.runUntilCurrent()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 796, in runUntilCurrent
    call.func(*call.args, **call.kw)
  File "so.py", line 50, in cbConnected
    d = proto.request(req)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/web/_newclient.py", line 1266, in request
    _requestDeferred = maybeDeferred(request.writeTo, self.transport)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 125, in maybeDeferred
    result = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/web/_newclient.py", line 703, in writeTo
    self._writeHeaders(transport, None)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/web/_newclient.py", line 535, in _writeHeaders
    hosts = self.headers.getRawHeaders('host', ())
exceptions.AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getRawHeaders'

Lost connection.  Reason: [Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone'>: Connection was closed cleanly.
]
```

That should give you a good clue on where to look for your actual problem.

Incidentally, take a look at Paisley, a Twisted client for CouchDB: [paisley](https://github.com/smcq/paisley/)

There are a few branches, and in particular [my changes branch](https://github.com/thomasvs/paisley/tree/changes) has some change notification stuff you may be interested in.  I made a desktop applet that showed me tasks added to my CouchDB-based todo system.

It sounds like your changes are a) already in there or b) should go in there; and c) you should consider working with and contributing to Paisley.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Thomas, that was very helpful. I will debug my program using your input. Regarding paisley: I see that you have several open branches. Are you planning on merging those to the master branch (specially the changes branch). I will definitely consider contributing as soon as I get familiar with it.

Comment: I found the problem: for the request, the headers can not be None. At least the host must be specified, even though we have already given that information during the connection phase. With those changes, I am getting a _newclient.Response, but I do not know how to use that to get the couchdb data out of it. I was hoping to get json data ...

Comment: Yes, they should be merged.  I'm finishing a project using them to make sure the changes are right.  As for Response - I think you have to register with deliverBody to get the body.  Paisley was ported to _newclient, so take a look.

Comment: You really shouldn't be importing `_newclient`, as it's a private implementation module.  However, the lack of a public name for `RequestGenerationFailed` is a bug.  See http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/5310.